# Path components of space of almost complex structures

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a closed oriented smooth 4-manifold which admits an almost complex structure. The Ehresmann-Wu theorem states that a class $c\in H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is realizable as the first Chern class of some almost complex structure $M$ if and only if 
$$w_2(TM)=c \mod 2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad
c^2=2\chi+3\sigma,
$$ 
where $\chi$ and $\sigma$ are the Euler characteristic and signature of $M$. Let 
$$
\mathcal{J}(M,c)=\{J\in \mathcal{J}(M)\mid c_1(TM,J)=c, \quad J\; \text{ is orientation compatible}\}
$$
be the set of almost complex structures on $M$ with first Chern class $c$ and which are compatible with the orientation of $M$.

Then it can be shown that 
$$
\pi_0(\mathcal{J}(M,c))\cong \mathrm{Tor}_2(H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}))\times \left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \frac{H^3(M;\mathbb{Z})}{H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})\cup c}\right).
$$
See for example section 4.1 of McDuff-Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*. In particular, if $M$ is simply connected, then $\mathcal{J}(M,c)$ has precisely two connected components.

**My question:** Is there an analogous formula for $\pi_0(\mathcal{J}(M,c))$ for 6-manifolds (maybe with more assumptions like simply connected)? If what happens in the cases of $\mathbb{CP}^3$ or $S^6$?

Answer (score 2):

See proposition 8 of "CUBIC FORMS AND COMPLEX 3-FOLDS" by Okonek and Van-de-Ven. I restate it here for completeness.

Suppose $M$ is an oriented smooth $6$-manifold without $2$-torsion in $H^{3}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ then there is $1:1$ correspondence:

Homotopy classes of almost complex structures on $M$ $\leftrightarrow $ Integral lifts of $w_{2}(M)$.